# проблема с url функцией в django

Tags: python, django

Сама ошибка:

> Reverse for 'viewListing' not found. 'viewListing' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

сама форма:

```
 <form action = "{% url 'auctions:viewListing' itemID %}" method = "post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type = "number" name = "bid_price" placeholder = "Input Bid">
    <input type = "submit">
</form>
```

Как это можно пофиксить?

urls.py:

```
    path("listing/<int:itemID>", views.viewListing, name = "listing")
```

Comment: Ну наверное добавить `viewListing` в `urls.py` например?

Comment: Покажите ваш файл `urls.py`

Comment: @wchistow обновил пост

Comment: Ну если вы написали name `listing`, то значит именно его и используйте вместо `viewListing` наверное?

Comment: Я исправил, проблема оказалась в том, что мне надо было в context передать в html файл itemID

Answer (score 1):

Я исправил, проблема оказалась в том, что мне надо было в context передать в html файл itemID

```
context = {'itemID': itemID}
```

Таким образом будет следующее url:

```
<form action = "{% url 'auctions:listing' itemID %}" method = "post" name = "form">
```